# Count Unique Values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregation-framework

In the `$facet` stage of my mongoDB pipeline, because some records reference the same "customer.id", I need to count based on *unique* occurrences of "customer.id". I have tried this:

```
"totalCustomers" : [ { $group : { "$customer.id" : { $sum: 1 } } } ]
```

... but end up with the error: "The field name '$customer' cannot be an operator name".

I also tried this:

```
"totalCustomers" : [  { "$group" : { "_id" : "$customer.id", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 }}}   ]
```

... which doesn't error out, but that gives me all the records, rather than the numerical count of all those records.

What is the syntax for doing a count on every unique "$customer.id" from my data set? My understanding is that I need to use `$sum` within either a `$group` or `$project` stage, but am unclear as to the specifics of what this is supposed to look like.

To clarify further, if my data structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
  id: '111',
  someProp: <value>,
  customer: { id: '222' } 
  },
  {
  id: '112',
  someProp: <value>,
  customer: { id: '222' } 
  }
]
```

... I should end up with "totalCustomers: 1".

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to return all the records, rather than the count on the total.

Comment: The second snippet is a valid query. If you don't get what you expect, it's probably because of the data structure. Give some examples of what you are trying to group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it within two steps:

```
[
    {$group: {_id: null, customerIds: {$addToSet: '$customer.id'}}},
    {$project: {uniqueCustomers: {$size: '$customerIds'}}}
]
```

This will create a set (technically an array without duplicates) with all `customer.id`s and get its size.

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly what I needed. It makes sense to use $addToSet in this kind of circumstance. Many thanks, @Radoslow.